# Function Conceptual Help: Check if a variable exists in workspace MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, variables, workspace, concept

I am stuck with this very simple function. I am making some fundamental conceptual mistake which I cannot see. Any help would be super appreciated.

I want to use the code to check if a certain variable is present in the work space. If it is then no operation should be performed else a certain operation should be performed for ex read in a file. 
Thanks

Minimal reproducible example:

```
function workspace_variables_check(variable_to_check)
% Loop over all the Variables in the Workspace to get the all the variable names
workspace_variables = who('-regexp',variable_to_check);
if isempty(workspace_variables) % A variable by this name is present in the workspace
    disp('Absent in Workspace')
    output = 1 ;
else                            % A variable by this name is not present in the workspace
    disp('Present from Workspace')
    output = 0 ;
end
```

Example : 
    a = 1; b = 1; c = 1: d = 1:

Test the function:

```
workspace_variables_check('d')
workspace_variables_check('b')
workspace_variables_check('c')
workspace_variables_check('a')
```

Output of the function:

```
Variable NOT Present

ans =

     0

Variable Present

ans =

     1

Variable Present

ans =

     1

Variable Present

ans =

     1
```

Comment: What's your problem? I suspect you don't want to be looking in the `currently active workspace` as returned by `who` ([docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html)), i.e. this function's workspace. You probably need to do something like `evalin` on the base workspace, but you've not described what you're trying to achieve or why it isn't working so it's impossible to tell. You need to [edit] in a [mcve] with your expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the code:

1) When **who** is called by the function, it returns the list of variables available *in the function workspace*, not in the base workspace. If you remove the semicolon from the first line of code, you will see the output from the function:

```
workspace_variables = who('-regexp',variable_to_check)
```

When you run the function from the command line, you see that the function has only one variable when this line executes, and that variable is the input variable "variable_to_check":

```
>> workspace_variables_check('b')

workspace_variables =

  1×1 cell array

  {'variable_to_check'}
```

All of the variables a,b,c etc are in the "base" workspace, and a separate function does not have access to them.
The concept of which variables are available to a function is called *scope*. Here is a link to a [blog post](http://www.matlabtips.com/variable-scope-memory-spaces-in-matlab/) that discusses scope in MATLAB.

2) The other thing that is happening is that the same line of code performs a regexp against the name of the variables present, which is the string 'variable_to_check'. So the characters 'a','b','c' are all matched by the regexp, but 'd' does not. So you can check for a mystery variable "v":

```
>> workspace_variables_check('v')

workspace_variables =

  1×1 cell array

  {'variable_to_check'}

Present from Workspace
```

Also "ch", "var", etc. I bet that made the debugging confusing :)

If you want a function to check for variables in the "base" workspace (which is what you use from the command line), you can use this:

```
function output = workspace_variables_check(variable_to_check)
% Check to see if a variable exists in the Base Workspace

exist_string = sprintf('exist(''%s'')',variable_to_check);
workspace_variables = evalin('base',exist_string);

if workspace_variables == 1      % A variable by this name is present in the workspace
    disp('Present from Workspace')
    output = 1 ;
else                        % A variable by this name is not present in the workspace
    disp('Absent in Workspace')
    output = 0 ;
end
```

Comment: Correct, though it would be more logical to examine the caller’s workspace rather than the base workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function [`exist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html). In fact you want to do the following

```
if exist(variable_to_check,'var') == 1
% do something
end
```

Note that the function will return the integer code independently whether you specify the search type (here `'var'`) or not but it is recommended for speed and clarity.

> ```
> 0 — name does not exist or cannot be found for other reasons. For example, if name exists in a restricted folder to which MATLAB® does not have access, exist returns 0.
> 1 — name is a variable in the workspace.
> 2 — name is a file with extension .m, .mlx, or .mlapp, or name is the name of a file with a non-registered file extension (.mat, .fig, .txt).
> 3 — name is a MEX-file on your MATLAB search path.
> 4 — name is a loaded Simulink® model or a Simulink model or library file on your MATLAB search path.
> 5 — name is a built-in MATLAB function. This does not include classes.
> 6 — name is a P-code file on your MATLAB search path.
> 7 — name is a folder.
> 8 — name is a class. (exist returns 0 for Java classes if you start MATLAB with the -nojvm option.)
> ```

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with the code that I tried? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Tarun, in fact, I can't. The code looks OK (though I hardly have ever seen someone using this trick/woraround). I assume that the falty provided base-code rather a formatting error than the cause, right? (there is a colon and not a semicolon after `c=1`. That would explain why `d` does not exist but must have raised a command-line error earlier)

Comment: The problem with OP’s code and this code is that they check if the variable exists in the function’s workspace, not the caller’s workspace.